# When I run a bash from another bash {{1..5}} stops working why?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

## Problem

I have two bash files: **run.sh** and **run_1.sh**. When I try to call **run_1.sh** from **run.sh** the loop doesnt work anymore as you can see in the output. I really don't understand what's happening. **run_1.sh** is located in sub-directory **/runs/**.

---

## run.sh

```
1        #!/bin/bash
2        
3        for i in {1..10}
4        do
5         echo $i
6        done
7    
8    sh /runs/run_1.sh
```

---

## runs/run_1.sh"

```
  #!/bin/bash
        
        for i in {11..20}
        do
         echo $i
        done
```

---

## output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
{11..20}
```

Comment: Instead of `sh /runs/run_1.sh` use `bash /runs/run_1.sh`

Comment: @anubhava oh lol thank you. what is the difference. Can you put it as the answer please

Comment: The difference is that `sh` is POSIX sh, and it doesn't support bash-only features.

Comment: BTW, this is right there in the bash tag info page (item #2 in "before asking about problematic code") at http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info. This is a very, very, **very** duplicate question.

Comment: [More](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3320/what-are-the-fundamental-differences-between-the-mainstream-nix-shells) than you probably will ever need at a unix quiz night on shells.

Comment: BTW, the loop doesn't stop working -- it's the expansion that doesn't work; the behavior of `for` doesn't change in any immediately relevant way. You can test this by comparing `echo {{1..5}}` between both shells, no `for` loop required to demonstrate the difference.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this line:

```
sh /runs/run_1.sh
```

use `bash` to execute other script

```
bash /runs/run_1.sh
```

Plain old bourne shell `sh` doesn't expand `{11..20}` which is a `bash` feature.

Comment: How come sh won't read the shebang and then execute bash instead?

Comment: shebang is honored if script is executed like this `/runs/run_1.sh`

Comment: So if I typed `bash ./myfile.rb` and myfile is a genuine ruby script it will try to interpret it and spit out a load of errors?